# Getting error 422 (Unprocessable Entity) while doing AJAX in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to insert data of a user in the database using ajax. I have done it without it and it worked fine. Now it is giving me error 422. The code is given below:

> **UserController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
        $inputArray = array(
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        );
        $value = User::create($inputArray);
        !is_null($value) ? $message = "User Added Successfully" : $message = "User not Added";
        return json_encode(array($message));
    }
```

> **Index.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" {{-- action="{{ route('users.store') }}" --}} id="createform">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf" value="{{Session::token()}}">
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input type="text"
                                    name="name"
                                    class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    value="{{ old('name') }}"
                                    placeholder="Full name"
                                    id="name">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <div class="input-group-text">@icon('user')</div>
                            </div>
                            @error('name')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input type="email"
                                    name="email"
                                    value="{{ old('email') }}"
                                    class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    placeholder="Email"
                                    id="email">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <div class="input-group-text">@icon('envelope')</div>
                            </div>
                            @error('email')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input type="password"
                                    name="password"
                                    class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    placeholder="Password"
                                    id="password">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <div class="input-group-text">@icon('lock')</div>
                            </div>
                            @error('password')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input type="password"
                                    name="password_confirmation"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Retype password"
                                    id="password_confirmation">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <div class="input-group-text">@icon('lock')</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="msg"></div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnadd">Add User</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

> **jqajax.js**

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    jQuery("#btnadd").on('click', addInfo);
    function addInfo(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = jQuery('#name').val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var password_confirmation = $("#password_confirmation").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/users",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                _token: $("#csrf").val(),
                name: name,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                password_confirmation: password_confirmation
            },
            success: function (dataResult) {
                var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                msg = "<div class='alert alert-dark mt-3'>dataResult.message</div>";
                $("#msg").html(msg);
                $("#createform")[0].reset();
                showdata();
            },
        });

    }
});
```

The Error I am getting is **app.js:14653 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/users 422 (Unprocessable Entity)**

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I have tried serializing method and sometimes I  started to get csrf token error 419 then I added it in the header and so on but now that error is gone. For this, I have tried serializing and different data manipulations cuz I think this error is due to data I am passing but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255']
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        $returnError['name'] = $errors->first('name');
        return json_encode($returnError);
    } else {
        $inputArray = array(
            'name' => $request['name']
        );
        $value = User::create($inputArray);
        !is_null($value) ? $message = "User Added Successfully" : $message = "User not Added";
        return json_encode(array($message));
    }
}
```